# OnClickListner so hard

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

So i have a problem to set an action button,

That is all fils.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.man.test4"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.man.test4.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.man.test4.Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Mldc" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Mcf" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Meco" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".adf" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Options" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5.0dip" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/scan_btn"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mldc"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    android:text="@string/options" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/meco"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adf"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adf"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    android:text="@string/meco" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mcf"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/meco"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mldc"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    android:text="@string/mcf" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mldc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mcf"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    android:text="@string/mldc" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/scan_btn"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/scan"
    android:onClick="launchScanner"
    android:text="@string/scan" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/adf"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/options"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    android:text="@string/adf" />
```

Main.java

```
package com.man.test4;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class Main extends Activity {

Button mldc,mcf,meco,adf,options;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    mldc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mldc);
    mcf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mcf);
    meco = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meco);
    adf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adf);
    options = (Button) findViewById(R.id.options);

    mldc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Mldc.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
    mcf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Mcf.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
}
    });
    meco.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Meco.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
    adf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, adf.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
    options.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Options.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
        }

    }
```

for the options button for example options.java

```
package com.man.test4;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Options extends Activity {

Button options;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);


}
```

}

So the problem is when i wlick on a button , this button don't open an other activity, i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Just nothing happens or you get an error?

Comment: So when i click on the options button there are nothing happens. If someone whould more informations, my project source and the apk files can be downloaded from this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/os9xqz7h2vdeuiz/projet.rar I think that i was made all good, i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Repeating the same comment to all answers will not help you. Not that many people will have time/interest in downloading your project. Don't be lazy, explain the issue properly and try all of the recommended solutions

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `options activity` in your manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.man.test4.Options">
</activity>
```

If that doesn't work, post your stacktrace.

Comment: So when i click on the options button there are nothing happens.

If someone whould more informations, my project source and the apk files can be downloaded from this link                 http://www.mediafire.com/download/os9xqz7h2vdeuiz/projet.rar

I think that i was made all good, i don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the fully qualified name for your activities in the manifest file. And also, post your error log cat if any or what happens when you click the buttons.

Comment: So when i click on the options button there are nothing happens. If someone whould more informations, my project source and the apk files can be downloaded from this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/os9xqz7h2vdeuiz/projet.rar I think that i was made all good, i don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So when i click on the options button there are nothing happens.

If someone whould more informations, my project source and the apk files can be downloaded from this link [My project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/os9xqz7h2vdeuiz/projet.rar)

I think that i was made all good, i don't know what is the problem.